# Integrating Buddypress, Wootumblog and WPMU Sitewide tags

Tags: buddypress

Judging by the lack of information when I perform a search, I may be one of the few people that has tried to get these plugins playing nicely together. When all is sorted and the site is live, I’ll post up a link to hopefully inspire a few other sites to try them out together.

Basically what I have is a standard WP multisite/BP configuration, to which I’ve installed the WooTumblog plugin at the network level and then added ‘function woo_tumblog_type’ and ‘function woo_tumblog_short_title’ to the functions.php file in the child theme used by my sub-sites. Both my main theme and child themes are heavily adapted from the BP Default theme.

Somewhat frustrated by the lack of front-end publishing tools for Wordpress and keen to use the WooTumblog dashboard (which uses javascript enabled panel changes depending on whether a user wishes to publish a video, image, quote, link or article), I decided to customise the admin area for users to look identical to the site’s front-end, then I removed all other dashboard widget boxes (using unset($wp_meta_boxes…) and all the admin sidebars and menus (using remove_submenu_page()) and also customised the admin bar.

The result is a a user admin dashboard that looks as if it is a part of the main site. The configurations are triggered by user level – using

I came slightly unstuck when I implemented the WPMU sitewide tags plugin which copies everything on the network into a single site which can them be used to produce cross-site tags, searches and display all the latest network posts. On the front end of my main site (where all the latest posts are displayed) I display a tumblog icon against each post based on its taxonomy (i.e. video, image, quote…) . I have built a 'catch image' function which displays the first image from a post and where there is no image (such as for a quote or video) it displays a default thumbnail.

Everything works fine except I cannot get the custom taxonomy to reach the main site (or tag blog) so that I can then customise the presentation of these sub-site posts.

I've been in contact with Ron Rennick (who maintains WPMU SWT) and Jeff Pearce (who is the woo themes developer behind wootumblog). They've both shared their advice, but I've not worked with classes, actions and filters so I'm finding it difficult translating their advice into tangible changes in my code.

If anyone has a spare moment and would like to give it a go, here's a link to Ron's advice; http://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-buddypress-and-sitewide-tags-to-play-nicely?replies=10

With Ron's input I created the following plugin..

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: SWT Custom Taxonomy
Description: Addition of new custom taxonomies to the wpmu sitewide tags plugin.
Version: 1.0
Author: CitizenSlide
License: GPL2
*/

function my_swt_custom_tax_filter( $taxonomies ) {
$taxonomies[] = 'tumblog';
return $taxonomies;
}
add_filter( 'sitewide_tags_custom_taxonomies', 'my_swt_custom_tax_filter' );
?>
```

But as far as I can tell, there is no change in the output written to the SWT tag blog.

Anyone with any thoughts? I 'just' want to carry one (custom taxonomy) field from a sub-site post through to the main site using the sitewide tags plugin.  How hard can that really be?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin that you have built with Ron's advice looks like it should work. What it does, in brief, is adds 'tumblog' to the list of taxonomies that SWT looks at (and copies) when copying a post from its home blog to the tags blog.

The kicker is that this plugin will only work if you are running it across the entire network. Make sure it's network-activated, or in `mu-plugins`, so that it runs on every blog.